# supporting multiple screens

Tags: android

What cares must be taken to support multiple screens and different screen densities.
How it can be done(multiple screens - small, medium, large and Tablets)
How to test the application to ensure that it support multiple screen.
does it possible to test in Emulator.

Comment: Yes it's possible to test in emulator, android provides an official guide for this - http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: The latest name for this is "responsive design". If you Google for that or "responsive web design", you will find plenty of articles to help you out. It's just a matter of knowing what we're calling it this week.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer this documeation by android [Supporting multiple screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)